# Apache POI gridline dissapear after setting new cellstyle

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, cell

I am generating HSSF style workbook.

After creating new CellStyle my grid lines disappear. I don't want to put BorderStyle.DORDER_THIN because that is not like just grid line. I has bigger edges.
I have tried in sheet currentSheet.setDisplayGridlines(false)

my code:

```
HssfCellStyle hssfCellStyle = hssfWorkbook.createCellStyle
Font hssfFont = this.getFontFor(rowCellStyle.cellFont)
hssfCellStyle.setFont(hssfFont)
               hssfCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(rowCellStyle.backgroundColor.hssfColor.getIndex)             
hssfCellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

so this makes disappear gdi lines

Comment: What version of POI are you using?

Comment: Have you tried making your cell look like you want in Excel, then reading it in Apache POI and checking what the Cell Style has on it?

Comment: thanks for your answers guys. I was misunderstanding the default gird, I was thinking of it as a normal grid but it0s not. Answer is bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I was little bit stupid. 
Default grid line is not border, so if you put some color then that default grid line is filled with that color.
Default Cell color is AUTOMATIC -> what means TRANSPARENT and because of that default grid can been seen.

default color = new HSSFColor.AUTOMATIC()